# Marking the last character from the matched string

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to mark the last character from the matched string in regex101 or notepad++ regex. To be marked the last space before the }.

Here’s my example(tried), Regex:
https://regex101.com/r/0QNOD1/1

input:

```
[]*}+%>++~€_€<]%,!!_€~
“ABC/A1/YY-“+abc1 
    }
!£|€_€{^}?![+}|!¥]
“ABC/A2/YY-“+abc2
    }
18,&4&5&4&&1$&((&&1
“ABC/A3/YY-“+abc7
    }
```

Result After Replacement

```
[]*}+%>++~€_€<]%,!!_€~
“ABC/A1/YY-“+abc1 
    SEND}
!£|€_€{^}?![+}|!¥]
“ABC/A2/YY-“+abc2
    SEND}
18,&4&5&4&&1$&((&&1
“ABC/A3/YY-“+abc7
    SEND}
```

Comment: Yes. But there are a lot of } in my real data so I need to specify the pattern with ABC\/A\d\+/YY-“\+abc\d+\s+

Comment: ok please try: `ABC/A\d+/YY-“\+abc\d+\s*(.)?+}`

Comment: When I marked it in notedpad++ and replace with new string it will overwrite the old matched string…

Comment: I just added the result below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search using this regex:

```bash
ABC/A\d+/YY-“\+abc\d+\s*[\s\S]?+\K(?=})
```

And replace it with:

```
SEND
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0QNOD1/3)

**RegEx Details:**

- `ABC/A`: Match `ABC/A`
- `\d+`: Match 1+ digits
- `/YY-“\+abc`:
- `\d+`: Match 1+ digits
- `\s*`: Match 0+ whitespaces
- `[\s\S]?+`: Match an optional character including line break. `+` after `?` is possessive quantifier.
- `\K`: Reset match info
- `(?=})`: Lookahead to make sure we have `}` at next position